# Sorting multiple API's by price in a table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, api

This is going to be confusing but probably an easy answer.

I have two api links in a json format. Pulling data into a table.

At the moment, all of the API1 is being put in the table first and below that API2 is then being put in.

Both of the api's have prices in £XX.XX format.

What I am looking for is the table to be sorted by price. So that for example API1 first 2 results are the cheapest, then API2 then API1 and so on and so forth.

I have posted my code below for you to look at.

Table.html

```
<table class="pull-left table-fill" id="Bananna">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="table-hover">Vendor</th>
    <th class="table-hover">Section</th>
    <th class="table-hover">Amount Of Tickets</th>
    <th class="table-hover">Price Per Ticket</th>
    <th class="table-hover">Link</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>

 </body>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/1.js"></script>
 <script src="js/2.js"></script>
```

1.js and 2.js are exactly the same.

```
       $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'API LINK HERE',

        success: function (json) {
           //var json = $.parseJSON(data);

           for(var i =0;i < json.results.length;i++) {

             var section = json.results[i].section;

             var no = json.results[i].avalible;

             var price = json.results[i].price;

             var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='viagogo.com'>Compare</button>";


             $("#Bananna").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+section+"</td><td>"+no+"</td><td>"+price+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
 $("#Bananna").find(".redirect-button").click(function(){
   location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
  });
               }
         },
           error: function(error){
               console.log(error);
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't touch the table until you've got both result sets, that's just going to make sorting more difficult. Define some global results array and populate it with the AJAX data using concat.

```
var results = [];
//on success of each AJAX call
results = results.concat(json.results);
```

To ensure both sets of data have been loaded before sorting just include the second AJAX call in the complete function of the first or use recursion if you may have additional AJAX requests in the future.

After you have all the data you can sort by price:

```
results.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.price-b.price;
});
```

Finally, step through the sorted array and append as you did before.

---

EDIT:

Instead of making a bunch of files which are all identical, define a recursive function to load an array of API urls like this:

```
function loadURLs(urls,callback){
    //are there more urls to AJAX?
    if(urls.length==0){
       //no: call the callback function
       callback();
    }else{
        //yes: make the AJAX call...
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: urls[0],
            success: function (json) {
                //put data into the results array
                results = results.concat(json.results);
                //load the remaining urls
                loadURLs(urls.slice(1),callback);     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function accepts an array of URL links. It will go through one by one and load the json data into the global results array. After it has gone through all the links it will call the callback function. Inside the callback function you can sort your array once and then append to your table. Your final js would look something like this:

```
//define loadURLs function here

//global results array
var results = [];
//define all your links links here
var myURLs = ['API LINK 1','API LINK 2'];
loadURLs(myURLs,function(){
   //all json data has been loaded, sort
   results.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.price-b.price;
    });
    //iterate over the sorted array and append
    for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
        //append to table
    } 
});
```

Comment: Forgive me. Extremely out of my element doing this. The code you have provided needs to be put where? The JSON is coming back from api links on a remote server so i can't change them and there is two different links in two different files.

Comment: Is there any reason you've separated the AJAX stuff into two different files?

Comment: just for ease. Its becomes alot of code to navigate through if i add more apis.

Comment: i could take it out of the seprate files. But im still at a loss where to put the text >.<

Comment: so, ive lied a ltitle. The data is a little changed in the json results. So for example the `json.results[i].price` will be a littlle different on each api sorry!

Comment: Also, the Code has a syntax error on line 20. Ideas?